# Splitting all.js into multiple files - Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, split, gulp, minify, uglifyjs

I have been working on an Angular JS based application. I have written a set of gulp commands to uglify/remove comments from JS code. When I run the web application and monitor the network traffic, I noticed that minified(uglified) 'all.js' file consumes quite a lot of time to be loaded (please forget about the caching).

1. I believe that splitting the all.js file (before or after processing) in to several pieces (let's say four pieces) will improve the application loading time. Please mention if you think there is/are better way(s).
2. Still I am struggling to find a way to get an approach to above mentioned method under #1. Still no luck :-( Please advice me.

[image]

**Gulpfile**

```
// include plug-ins
'use strict';
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var htmlbuild = require('gulp-htmlbuild');
var plugins = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
var es = require('event-stream');
var clean = require('gulp-clean');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var strip = require('gulp-strip-comments');
var pump = require('pump');

// pipe a glob stream into this and receive a gulp file stream 
var gulpSrc = function (opts) {
    var paths = es.through();
    var files = es.through();
    paths.pipe(es.writeArray(function (err, srcs) {
        var fixedFiles = [];
        for (var i=0; i < srcs.length; i++)
        {
            fixedFiles[i] = srcs[i].replace("~", ".");
            console.log(fixedFiles[i]);
        }
        gulp.src(fixedFiles, opts).pipe(files);
    }));

    return es.duplex(paths, files);
};

var jsBuild = es.pipeline(
  plugins.concat('all.js'),
  gulp.dest('./Scripts/')
);

gulp.task('clean', function () {
    return pump(gulp.src('./Scripts/all.js')
            .pipe(clean({ force: true })));
});
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I currently have the same problem. My minified  app.js file is 26mb and takes way to long to load. I'm thinking of a lazyload approach using https://oclazyload.readme.io/docs. Have you tried this?

Comment: Also another approach might be service workers - https://mobiforge.com/design-development/caching-with-service-workers-the-easy-way

Comment: @synapze, Apologies for replying late. I used a different approach to achieve the goal. This method did not work for me. Thanks for sharing the link about service workers.